# Populate 3rd dropdown with ajax function

Tags: ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
```

**//CONC**

```
Aveiro=new Array("Albergaria-a-Velha","Anadia","Aveiro");
Beja=new Array("Aljustrel","Almodôvar","Alvito","Barrancos","Beja");
```

**//FREG**

```
Albergaria-a-Velha=new Array("Albergaria-a-Velha e Valmaior","Alquerubim");
Anadia=new Array("Amoreira da Gândara, Paredes do Bairro e Ancas");
Aljustrel=new Array("Aljustrel e Rio de Moinhos","Ervidel","Messejana");

populateSelect();

$(function() {

      $('#cat').change(function(){
        populateSelect();
    });

});


function populateSelect(){
    cat=$('#cat').val();
    $('#item').html('');

    if(cat=='Aveiro'){
        Aveiro.forEach(function(t) { 
            $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

    if(cat=='Beja'){
        Beja.forEach(function(t) {
            $('#item').append('<option>'+t+'</option>');
        });
    }

} 

});//]]>
```

> //HTML

```
<select id="cat">
        <option val="Aveiro">Aveiro</option>
        <option val="Beja">Beja</option>
        <option val="Braga">Braga</option>
        <option val="Bragança">Bragança</option>
        <option val="Castelo Branco">Castelo Branco</option>
        <option val="Coimbra">Coimbra</option>
        <option val="Évora">Évora</option>
    </select>
```

//Function populates concelho (CONC)

```
<select id="item">
</select>
```

**//what i want is to populate this 3rd with values under FREG**

```
<select id="freg">
</select>
```

**i'm trying to fill a third dropdown list with this function... but all that i tried doesn't work! Can anyone help me? i'm newbie! :S**

Answer (score 0):

Your variable naming is not correct. Variables should not contain a `hyphen (-)`. Rename the below variable in your `FREG`

```
Albergaria-a-Velha
```

You can use `underscore (_)` instead. Refer: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers